# why does the event listener in this throttling function behave like that?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, throttling

While I was learning about [throttling in javascript](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-throttling/), I came upon an event-listener behavior that I can't explain. Here is a simple throttling function.

```js
const btn=document.querySelector("#throttle"); 
      
    // Throttling Function 
    const throttleFunction=(func, delay)=>{ 
      
      // Previously called time of the function 
      let prev = 0;  
      console.log(prev); //This gets called only once and it is even before the button is clicked
      return (...args) => { 
        // Current called time of the function 
        let now = new Date().getTime();  
  
        // Logging the difference between previously  
        // called and current called timings 
        console.log(now-prev, delay);  //This however doesn't get called before the button is clicked
          
        // If difference is greater than delay call 
        // the function again. 
        if(now - prev> delay){  
          prev = now; 
  
          // "..." is the spread operator here  
          // returning the function with the  
          // array of arguments 
          return func(...args);   
        } 
      } 
    } 
    btn.addEventListener("click", throttleFunction(()=>{ 
      console.log("button is clicked") 
    }, 1500));
```

```html
<button id="throttle">Click Me</button>
```

I have two questions.

1. Why does `let prev = 0;` only get called once? i.e why doesn't
   `prev` get reset to 0 every time the function is called?
2. I have also noticed that `let prev = 0;` gets called before the button is even clicked, Why does this happen? and why doesn't the rest of the function get called before the button is clicked as well?

[This](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-throttling/) is where I found the code above. I have looked into `addEventListener` on MDN but to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Because `throttleFunction` is called immediately, and itself returns a second function. It's that second function that is called on the event listener.

Comment: Okay, I now understand why the second function doesn't get called at first. But I still do not understand why `throttleFunction` is called immediately.

Comment: Because you call it in the same line in which you call `addEventListener`. It then returns another function, which is passed as argument into `addEventListener`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.addEventListener()` method takes a reference to a function as its second argument, which it can invoke when your button is clicked. So something like this will fail to add the function as a click event handler:

```js
const sayHello = () => console.log("hello");
btn.addEventListener("click", sayHello());
```

In the above example JavaScript:

1. Sees the call to `addEventListener()`
2. Evaluates its arguments, which means calling the `sayHello()` function.

   2.1. `sayHello()` runs and returns `undefined`
3. Calls the `addEventListener()` method with `"click"` and `undefined` (the evaluated arguments)

Above the `sayHello()` is a function call, so it will execute as your event listener is added and before any clicks occur, resulting in the return value of `sayHello` being used as the second argument to `addEventListener()`, so the above code will evaluate to something like:

```
const sayHello = () => console.log("hello");
btn.addEventListener("click", undefined);
```

To correctly pass a reference to the event listener, you would need to pass a function that can then later be invoked by JS when a click occurs:

```
btn.addEventListener("click", sayHello);
```

With that in mind, your `throttleFunction()` argument is being called when you add your event listener, which means that the `throttleFunction` itself isn't what is being passed as the second argument to `addEventListener()`, but rather the return value. This may be a little clearer if you extract the callback to `throttleFunction`:

```
const fn = () => {console.log("button is clicked")};
// invoking the `throttleFunction` function with `()`
const clickHandler = throttleFunction(fn, 1500);
btn.addEventListener("click", clickHandler); // clickHandler is a reference to a function (a non-invoked/called function)
```

Since your `throttleFunction()` function is being invoked, the returned function from `throttleFunction` is being used as the argument for `addEventListener()`, not the throttleFunction itself. The returned function is only then executed when a click occurs. As a result, `let prev = 0;` is executed once when the throttleFunction is first called which is when click event listener is added, but the returned function is executed multiple times, as JS will call it only when you click on your button.

Comment: Thanks so much for this thorough explanation. The last code snippet you added to make things a little clearer actually confused me for a couple of minutes. But I now understand what's happening. Thanks again!

Comment: @bavShehata ahh, whoops, I changed the last code block now so it is a bit clearer for any future readers. Good to hear that it makes sense now :)