# Understanding debounce function logic flow, particularly for Event object - where does (...args) get it's values from?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I'm working through a Javascript course and am working with the following code. I understand almost all of it but I'm struggling with following and understanding the logic flow through the code, particularly for the event objects and I want to make sure I'm super clear on this before continuing.

Almost the exact same question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64727261/debounce-return/65941421#65941421) by someone else with the same confusion but I can't make sense of any answers unfortunately.

Here's what I *do* understand so far:

A key gets pressed -> The `debounce` function returns (and runs) with parameters `func` and `delay`. The `func` parameter passed in is the `onInput` function in this case, (which as I understand it, gets an event object returned to it automatically (by Javascript) when the `addEventListener` fires).

However, `onInput` is run nested inside the `debounce` function with `func.apply(null, args);` so I'm confused as to how the event objects get created and *passed through* the flow of the code when keys are pressed?

*My main question following from this, is how or where does `return (...args)` within the `debounce` get its spread parameters from?*

Doesn't the `debounce` function get passed the event object in this case and not `onInput`? If so, how does `onInput` get access to the event object?

Here's the code:

```
const fetchData = async (searchTerm) => {
    const response = await axios.get('http://www.omdbapi.com/', {
        params: {
            apikey: '6459bge8',
            s: searchTerm
        }
    });

    console.log(response.data);
};

const input = document.querySelector('input');


const debounce = (func, delay) => {
    let timeoutId;
  
//Where is ...args getting it's values from?
    return (...args) => {
        console.log(args);
      
        if (timeoutId) {
            clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        }
        timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
            func.apply(null, args);
        }, delay);
    };
};

const onInput = (evt) => {
    fetchData(evt.target.value);
  };
  
input.addEventListener('input', debounce(onInput, 500));
```

Also I can't make sense of when I comment out the code within the returned function like this:

```
const debounce = (func, delay) => {
    let timeoutId;
  
    return (...args) => {
        console.log(args);
      
        // if (timeoutId) {
        //     clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        // }
        // timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
        //     func.apply(null, args);
        // }, delay);
    };
};
```

The passed in `func` never runs but the console.log(args) still shows `InputEvents` in the console when a key is pressed suggesting the args are coming from elsewhere and not set by `func.apply(null, args);`?

Comment: It gets those args from whatever calls it. debounce is a *higher order function*, it returns a function that in this case is passed as the callback to addEventListener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main thing to understand with your code is that the `addEventListener()` function isn't in charge of calling the `debounce()` function. The `debounce()` function is called when the `addEventListener` gets added to the input element, not when the input event occurs. This is because calling `debounce()` invokes the function, passing whatever it returns as the second argument to `addEventListener()`. With that in mind, you function can be re-written as this:

```
const inputHandler = debounce(onInput, 500); // debounce returns a function
input.addEventListener('input', inputHandler); // the returned function is used in the addEventListener function
```

So the function that is returned by `debounce()` is called when an input occurs (not the `debounce` function itself, as this is called when the addEventListener() method is called, which is immediately when the interpreter meets this line and not when an input occurs).

> Doesn't the debounce function get passed the event object in this case
> and not onInput? If so, how does onInput get access to the event
> object?

With the above explanation in mind, the returned function from `debounce()` is what gets passed as the second argument to `addEventListener()`. As a result, the returned function acts as the callback and gets passed the event object, which it has accesses to through `...args`. In the code-block above, that means `inputHanlder` gets passed the event object when it gets invoked by JS when an input event occurs. So `debounce()` never gets passed the event argument, it's the inner returned function that gets access to the event argument.

As the returned function (ie: the inner function in your code example), gets passed the event object, it can access it via `args`. The inner function then invokes/calls the `onInput` function with the event object using `func.apply(null, args);`.

---

As for your last example, the `func` function never runs as it is never called anywhere. It is passed into your function, but it never gets invoked/executed (unlike in the first example where it *does* get called using `.apply()`). The InputEvent still gets logged though, as the `addEventListener()` is what invokes the callback returned when the input occurs. As a result, the inner function still has access to the event object.

Comment: Thanks very much for your detailed reply. I've worked through and think the penny has dropped: The anonymous function within the `debounce` function effectively runs "in-place" of the 'debounce(onInput, 500)' call in `addEventListener`. This means that Javascript passes the event object created on 'input' into the anonymous function instead of the `debounce` function. That's where the `(...args)` gets it's value(s) from, which in this case is (only?) an event object(?). I'm still confused however that `debounce` gets called on page load as I thought it only gets run on 'input'?

Comment: @Diagonali No worries, sounds like you understand it a little better now. There is a difference between a _function call_ (`someFunc()`), and a function reference (one yet to be called) ie: `someFunc`. When JS sees `someFunc()` the `()` at the end of it tells JS to invoke `someFunc()`, irrespective of where it's being called. Since you are _calling_ `debounce()`, JS will invoke it when the page loads and provide  / whenever it comes across the function call. If you were to pass just `debounce (and not the called version of it), then it would only be called by JS when an input occurs.

Comment: I gave a similar answer here a few days ago which you might also want to take a look that explains the steps that occurs when JS comes across the call to `.addEventListener()`: [why does the event listener in this throttling function behave like that?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66289434) it might clear some things up. (oh, and yes, `event` is the only argument passed to the callback)

Comment: Ah, that explains the difference between function calls and references perfectly. It's pretty obvious now you point it out, I probably should have remembered that! I'll check out the other answer you gave for more info. I can continue with the course now knowing I'm not skipping over understanding anything! Appreciate your help.